# alias in index controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm very sorry I ask directly.

My Database:

**`id | A | B | C | D`**

And this is my controller:

```
$this->db->select("*")
         ->select('A + B + C as total_X')
         ->select('total_X - D as remains_Y')
         ->from('my_table')
.........
.........
......... another codes
```

This is the problem:

**`Unknown column 'total_X' in 'field list'`**

I'm little bit confused how to get "***remains_Y***" the addition from *A, B, and C* as ***total_X*** and I need to get "***remains_Y***" from ***(total_X - D)***.

What is the right code/syntax to get the Y?

Thank you so much for the help.

Best Regards,

Kris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("*, A + B + C as total_X, A + B + C - D as remains_Y")
         ->from('my_table')
```